# Convert SQL UPDATE statement to php with if else condition (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make php code with SQL Update Statement in Codeigniter.

If I execution code in Codeigniter, the data in database will be updated too.

I want to update one column (ID_STATUS) but with several condition.

The connection column '`ID_STATUS`' with column '`lama`' and '`estimasi`'

My table name is "pelayanan".

`ID_STATUS` is PK from table "status".

So, Column `ID_STATUS` in table "pelayanan" is foreign key from table "status".

I tried with this query, but, It isn't if else condition yet.

**condition 1 :**

```
UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` 
SET `pelayanan`.`ID_STATUS` = '1' 
WHERE `pelayanan`.`LAMA` <> `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI`;
```

**condition 2:**

```
UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` 
SET `pelayanan`.`ID_STATUS` = '2' 
WHERE `pelayanan`.`LAMA` = `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI`;
```

That is the query on mysql. But I want to convert that query to php code (Codeigniter).

How come It will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first query is

```
UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` 
SET `pelayanan`.`ID_STATUS` = '1' 
WHERE `pelayanan`.`LAMA` <> `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI`;
```

convert it as follows:

```
$update_data=array('ID_STATUS'=>'1');
$this->db->where('LAMA <>','ESTIMASI');
$this->db->update('pelayanan',$update_data);
```

your second query is

```
UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` 
SET `pelayanan`.`ID_STATUS` = '2' 
WHERE `pelayanan`.`LAMA` = `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI`;
```

convert it as follows:

```
$update_data=array('ID_STATUS'=>'2');
$this->db->where('LAMA','ESTIMASI');
$this->db->update('pelayanan',$update_data);
```

I have remove database name. database name will be selected in connection and and did required to mentioned it here.

Answer (score 1):

**condition 3:**

- **a.** both `LAMA` and `ESTIMASI` are null.
- **b.** `LAMA` is null
- **c.** `ESTIMASI` is null

If you want to update all rows in the table, based on the values of `LAMA` and `ESTIMASI`, you could do that in one fell swoop with one UPDATE statement.

```
  UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` p 
     SET p.`ID_STATUS`
         = CASE 
             WHEN p.`LAMA`  = p.`ESTIMASI` THEN '2'
             WHEN p.`LAMA` <> p.`ESTIMASI` THEN '1'
             WHEN p.`LAMA` IS NULL AND p.`ESTIMASI` IS NULL THEN p.`ID_STATUS`
             WHEN p.`LAMA` IS NULL THEN p.`ID_STATUS`
             ELSE p.`ID_STATUS`
           END
```

Note that assigning the current value of the `ID_STATUS` column back to the `ID_STATUS` column results in "no update".

Since the last two WHEN conditions return the same values as the ELSE, those could be removed. These were included just to illustrate possible handling of **condition 3**.

One small difference with this vs. the original is that it will attempt tto update every row in the table, including rows that have a NULL value in `LAMA` and/or `ESTIMASI`. That means any UPDATE triggers will be fired for those rows. To get *exactly* the same result as the original, you'd need to include a `WHERE` clause that excludes rows where `LAMA` is null or `ESTIMASI` is null. For example:

```
   WHERE p.`LAMA` IS NOT NULL
     AND p.`ESTIMASI` IS NOT NULL
```

As far as how to accomplish this same thing in PHP, someone else may be able to answer that. Personally, I'd just do it one SQL operation.

The ANSI-standard syntax is a bit verbose. A MySQL specific version that accomplishes the same thing is a bit shorter:

```
  UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` p 
     SET p.`ID_STATUS` = IFNULL((p.`LAMA`=p.`ESTIMASI`)+1,p.`ID_STATUS`)
```

**FOLLOWUP**

If `LAMA` and `ESTIMASI` are defined as `NOT NULL`, then you wouldn't have to deal with **condition 3**. (In the more general case, we don't necessarily have that guarantee, so I think it's better pattern to account for those conditions, even if they won't ever happen in our particular case.

For CodeIgniter ActiveRecord, you'd could try something like this:

```
 $this->db
   ->set('ID_STATUS', 'IFNULL((`LAMA`=`ESTIMASI`)+1,`ID_STATUS`)', FALSE)
   ->update('`dbhpl`.`pelayanan`');
```

Comment: `LAMA` and `ESTIMASI` is not NULL. I want to make that query become php code (Codeigniter)

Comment: when I execute that query in sql the result is ERROR. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BE = p.`ESTIMASI` THEN '2'
             WHEN p.`LAMA` <> p.`ESTIMASI` THEN '1'
' at line 4

Comment: Curious, I don't see any occurrence of the string **`BE`** in the example MySQL query. I can't tell where that string is coming from.